# How do I move an application from Default Web Site onto its own site?

Tags: iis

I have an existing application under the "Default Web Site" that is functioning but want to move it as its own "Site". What is the best approach to this as the functioning site has a lot of configuration to it.

I've tried creating a new site and copy/pasting the folder contents(c:/inetpub/wwwroot/application) over but that does not work.

In theory, if I could simply drag the application out of the "Default Web Site" and drop it to the "Sites" folder, that would be nice...

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean move from default ....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an old website you want to move to a different folder (like on a different hard drive w/ more memory), you can:

1. copy the folder to the website to the new location (making sure to reset all the file permissions b/c they are often not automatically copied),
2. open the site in IIS,
3. click "Basic settings" in the "Actions" panel on the right hand side of the screen,
4. change the "Physical path"
5. click ok

Do an app pool recycle afterwards to ensure everything takes effect

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do in IIS.

1. Right Click on Sites --> Add web Site (Make up a name for it)
2. Just set the physical path to the location of the application (You don't even have to move the application)